# How to delete the new firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I had created multiple databases in firebase real-time database in Blaze Plan. How can I delete the additional database? I downgraded to spark plan but it just disabled the additional database (not deleted). Is there any way to delete the additional database or it will stay there forever once created?

Answer (score 0):

you can go to your database in console firebase and move your mouse to the root of the tree and click **x** and confirm the delete and will be deleted.

Comment: I think this is not the solution. The question is about literally "DROP" database and not make a kind of "TRUNCATE". I hired a Blaze plan and I'm having the same problem, create an extra database for testing and I can not delete it and not "activate" or "deactivate".